# Is a photocopy of your passport valid ID in Turkey?

Tags: passports, paperwork, turkey

[This site](http://www.mysecuritychecker.com/#!turkey/fjlaf) tells me:

> It is illegal not to carry some form of photographic ID in Turkey. Carry a photocopy of your passport with you at all times.

However i want to double check.
While it would be nice to only carry a copy of my passport, I'ld rather be sure. I have been getting International SOS Security Advisories emails (part of the International SOS service contract my employer has, i think), which say:

> Expect increased security measures in areas affected by security force operations. Monitor local developments and allow extra time for journeys, carrying relevant identification to ease passage through security checkpoints and comply with all security force directives.

So I guess it is actually quiet likely that my ID will be checked at some point.

So is it true that I can use a photocopy of my passport?
I have 3 in good color.

Comment: You'll need an original document for customs, immigration and aircraft boarding procedures. However, when roaming the streets as a tourist you might want to leave your precious document at home and carry just a photocopy.

Comment: Any chance you could find a reference (even if it is just your personal experience of actually being stopped), cand make that an answer?

Comment: Wish I could. :) I always carry my ID on me as a force of habit, but was also never stopped when I was in Turkey. I'm afraid you'll have to wait for someone else to answer this.

Comment: You can keep your passport in a safe place under your clothes and have a copy of your passport in an easy to reach place. That way you have safety and still the ease of a copy at hand.

Answer (score 3):

No, photocopies of a passport are never a substitute for a passport as they're trivial to fake. However assuming that you look like an average European tourist this should be sufficient for the Turkish police to simply check your name in their local database.

Try to get some sort of an alternative official ID (such as your national ID card) or simply take the risk.